# ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND While resolving a named referrnce package element - PV01

Tags: boot, system-installation, bootloader, boot-repair

Ubuntu was running perfectly on my company's workstation. Then the electricity was cut off, and when it came back I got this error message.

[image]

```
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND While resolving a named reference package element - PV01
```